# Passing switch when calling other script

Tags: powershell

I am taking over a process (originally created by a vendor) that creates and configures a VM. The process can either create a VM in hyperv on a physical host, or in vsphere. This is a powershell script called migrate-storeservers.ps1.

As part of the configuration, migrate-storeservers.ps1 calls a script locally on the VM that performs database validation (Validate-StoreServerDB.ps1). In the event that the VM is created in vsphere, we only want certain validation tasks to run.

I added a vsphere switch to the Migrate-StoreServers.ps1, and added logic to the function that calls the database validation script.

Vsphere switch at top of script:

```
[cmdletbinding()]
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$Store,
    [switch]$FinalizeVm,
    [switch]$Vsphere,
    [switch]$SqlSafe,
    [switch]$FullAuto,
    [switch]$TestRun,
    $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
)
```

Function that calls database validation script, where $taskArgs are set based on Vsphere switch being used or not:

```
function validateDatabase($newServer, $newVmSession, $validateScript, $userScript, $moduleFile, $outLog){
    $global:currentTask = "Database Validation"
    Write-Debug "Current Task: $global:CurrentTask"
    Write-Host "Starting database validation on server: $newServer"
    $startTime = Get-Date
    Write-Host "Start time: $startTime" -ForegroundColor Green
    stageAaronsLiteModule -inModuleFile $moduleFile -inSession $newVmSession
    $dateString = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMddTHHmmss"
    $logName = $("DBValidate_" + $newServer.ToUpper() + "_" + $dateString + ".log")
    if($Vsphere){
    $taskArg = "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File {0} -Store {1} -LogPath {2} -LogFile {3} -Vsphere {4}" `
        -f $validateScript, $newServer, $outLog, $logName, $Vsphere
    } else{
    $taskArg = "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File {0} -Store {1} -LogPath {2} -LogFile {3}" `
        -f $validateScript, $newServer, $outLog, $logName
    }
    executeTask -inTaskName "DatabaseValidation" -inPsSession $newVmSession -inUserScript $userScript -inTaskArg $taskArg `
        -inMessage "Database Validation Script is starting. This takes about 2 minutes" -inCred $cred
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
    $logFound = copyLogToSource -inServer $newServer -inLog $($outLog + "\" + $logName) -outLogPath $LocalLogPath
    if(-not($logFound)){
        exitScript -inMessage "ERROR: Unable to find/copy log file" -failed $true
    }
    Start-Sleep 5
    parseLogForErrors -inLog $($LocalLogPath + "\" + $logName) -errorString "TerminatingError"
    $endTime = (Get-Date) - $startTime
    Write-Host "Validate Database completed in: $endTime" -ForegroundColor Green
}
```

In the validation script being called by the function I added a vsphere switch and logic that sets the tasks list based on if the vsphere switch is used.

```
[cmdletbinding()]
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$Store,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$LogPath,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$LogFile,
    [switch]$Vsphere,
    $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
)

########### Start Global Variable Section ###########
$sqlInstance = ($Store.ToUpper() + "\POS")
$sqlDatabase = "master"
$sqlConnectionTimeout = 60
$sqlQueryTimeout = 240
if($Vsphere){
$tasks = @(
        "GoNoGo_Store2016_Upgrade_10_CheckServerName",
        "GoNoGo_Store2016_Upgrade_20_CheckSQLVersion",
        "GoNoGo_Store2016_Upgrade_30_CheckDBOnline",
        "GoNoGo_Store2016_Upgrade_50_CheckDBExists"
    )
} else{
$tasks = @(
        "GoNoGo_Store2016_Upgrade_10_CheckServerName",
        "GoNoGo_Store2016_Upgrade_20_CheckSQLVersion",
        "GoNoGo_Store2016_Upgrade_30_CheckDBOnline",
        "GoNoGo_Store2016_Upgrade_40_CheckSysMergeArcticles",
        "GoNoGo_Store2016_Upgrade_50_CheckDBExists",
        "GoNoGo_Store2016_Upgrade_60_CheckReplicationStatus"
    )
}
```

My question is does the logic in the migrate-storeservers.ps1 look like it will pass the vsphere switch correctly to the validate-storeserverdb.ps1?

I am rather new to more advanced powershell like this and am concerned that the $taskArg for when the Vsphere switch is used are maybe not formatted correctly to pass the vsphere switch. The $taskArg for if the switch is not used was how the script was formatted before I added the switch logic.

Any input will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Avoid posting links to the code, and just post it here in plain text; makes it harder to help you as most people won't try to re-write it, or manually look for what you're talking about without a Ctrl+F function. I don't see the `$vsphere` switch as a parameter in your `migrate-storeservers.ps1` besides it being in an `if()` statement.

Comment: Thank you @AbrahamZinala 
I added the code blocks. The migrate-storeservers.ps1 is almost 1900 lines and has some proprietary/confidential information , so wasn't sure on best way to post that.

Comment: I still don't see the call to `validate-storeserverdb`.

Comment: The validateDatabase function in the post is used in another function called restoreDatabase, which is then used as part of another function called finalizeReplacementServer. 

There's a function called executeTask in validateDatabase function posted, which that is using the $taskArg variable. So the $taskArg is ultimately getting passed to the script.

$validateScript is the path to the script, and that is declared in the finalizeReplacementServer function.

All of that process works, the only change has been adding the vsphere switch and logic that sets the $taskArg.